# preg replace: replace all line breaks outside a title attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html, replace

in general I just want to use a function, which minifies my output (by removing line breaks and tabulators), but the problem is, with a normal code like that

```
return str_replace(array("\r\n", "\t"), '', $s);
```

also the title attributes (e.g. when you move over a word and a tooltip appears) are minified and the line breaks get lost. I want to keep line breaks, which are inside a title="textwithlinebreakhere", but remove all line breaks outside.

I have no idea how to realize that, so I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should use `preg_replace_all()` and then use `(?<!your_match_here)` and its siblings. What do I mean by siblings is negative_lookbehind and positive_lookbehind which conditions your search algorithm to see if a character is after or before a certain letter/sign/digit

Comment: The problem is, I also don't get the solution for matching the non negative match, so how I would only remove all line breaks inside a title tag. preg_replace('/title="(.*)"/','', $s); completely removes everything.. Sorry but I didn't really used this function and am stumped.

Comment: let's talk literally. you should tell the regexp: please remove all br tags but not thos that come after title=" and before ". Now you should force your brain to work this out. it is easy. let me find it and the I will post it

Comment: Yea, that sounds easy. I'm trying for hours now, but don't get it done.. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: regarding your example it is better for your to use lookaround:
preg_replace('/title="((?<!\r).*)"/','', $s);
The above statement says remove anything but only if it is not preceded by a \r character (some type of space, you can use your desired character such as \n)

Answer (score 0):

**Remove undesired characters with trim_all() - PHP  :**

This function was inspired from PHP's built-in function
trim
that removes undesired characters from the start and end of a string, and in case no such characters a provided as second argument to
trim
, removes white-space characters as provided in this list.

So, what does
trim_all()
do?

trim_all()
was intended to remove all instances of white-spaces from both ends of the string, as well as remove duplicate white-space characters inside the string. But, later on, I made it a general purpose function to do a little more than just white-space trimming and cleaning, and made it to accept characters-to-replace and characters-to-replace-with. With this function, you can:

1. normalize white-spaces, so that all multiple \r , \n , \t , \r\n , \0 , 0x0b , 0x20
       and all control characters can be replaced with a single space, and also trimed from both ends of the string;
2. remove all undesired characters;
3. remove duplicates;
4. replace multiple occurrences of characters with a character or string.

---

```
function trim_all( $str , $what = NULL , $with = ' ' )
{
    if( $what === NULL )
    {
        //  Character      Decimal      Use
        //  "\0"            0           Null Character
        //  "\t"            9           Tab
        //  "\n"           10           New line
        //  "\x0B"         11           Vertical Tab
        //  "\r"           13           New Line in Mac
        //  " "            32           Space

        $what   = "\\x00-\\x20";    //all white-spaces and control chars
    }

    return trim( preg_replace( "/[".$what."]+/" , $with , $str ) , $what );
}
```

This function can be helpful when you want to remove unwanted characters from users' input. Here is how to use it.

**Example Use :**

```
$full_name = trim_all( $_POST['full_name'] );
```

or

```
$full_name = trim_all( $full_name , "\t" , "" );
```